# iphone app Form validation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi how can I validate email address, username, fullname and date of birth for my registration form inside an iphone application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate with regular expressions in iPhone OS > 3.0 like so

```
    - (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate {
       NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
       NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 

       return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there a way we can test phone numbers as well. I have a field which takes phone number as an input and I need to know whether he provided correct phone number. something like ping a phone number functionality.

Comment: To test phone numbers, the general rule is if it follows a certain format, it's valid. For security reasons, I am fairly certain that you can't "ping a phone". The only way to test it would be to have a database of customer phone records, but again...not something publicly available

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way of validating an email address is using the US2FormValidator framework.

Example:

```
US2ValidatorEmail *emailValidator = [US2ValidatorEmail alloc] init];

US2ConditionCollection *collection1 = [emailValidator checkConditions:@"example@example.com"];  
// collection1 == nil, thus YES
US2ConditionCollection *collection2 = [emailValidator checkConditions:@"example@example."];       
// collection2.length > 0, thus NO
US2ConditionCollection *collection3 = [emailValidator checkConditions:@"example"];              
// collection3.length > 0, thus NO

BOOL isValid = [emailValidator checkConditions:@"example@example.com"] == nil;                  
// isValid == YES
```

You can simply use the US2ValidatorTextField instead of UITextField and connect to this US2ValidatorEmail. The text field will tell you what went wrong and if the user corrected the text.

The framework can be found on GitHub or Softpedia.

Comment: could you provide a more full implementation?  are there delegate methods to implement to make this work? i am having trouble..

Comment: @doug there is a sample project attached at GitHub which shows you how to use the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to only check phone numbers iOS also provides so called NSDataDetector's.

Usage like:

```
theTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

Read more about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html